# lightweight generics in objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, generics, xcode7

I am trying to implement the stack class with the lightweight generic.
But the code failed to compile because Xcode cannot find the definition of `ObjectType`

```
@implementation Stack
- (ObjectType)popObject     !!!!!!!!!Expected a type
{
    return self.allObjects.firstObject;
}
@end
```

It's strange because the header declaration doesn't generate any errors.

```
@interface Stack<__covariant ObjectType> : NSObject
- (ObjectType)popObject;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray<ObjectType> *allObjects;
@end
```

I could make it work by changing `ObjectType` to `id`. 
Are there better way to fix the error?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Objective-C generics really are lightweight, and were added to improve interoperability with Swift, not to make Objective-C code safer. Similar to nullability, think of generics as a way to annotate your interface rather than a reason to change your implementation.

Changing `ObjectType` to `id` *in the implementation* is the best way forward.

Further reading: [article on Objective C Generics](https://web.archive.org/web/20150805010143/http://drekka.ghost.io/objective-c-generics/). Read bob’s comment on that article if you want to know about `__covariant`.

Comment: That's right and to make it even more clear: generics just don't exist in the implementation, so don't bother changing your .m(m) files.

Comment: Article link is broken

Comment: Replaced the link with archive.org

Answer (score 2):

Only a presumption, but, if replacing `ObjectType` with `id` works, maybe you're using not a pointer type?

I mean, if you have `@interface ObjectType` somewhere, than in your `Stack` it should be `ObjectType*` both in `<...>` braces and in method return type

If it's not an issue, sorry for misleading

Comment: `NSArray.h` use the following declaration: ` - (ObjectType)objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;` . Apple doesn't provide the implementation file, though.

Comment: This is because ObjectType here can be not only pointer to ObjC object. It can be `id`, some GCD object, or Core Foundation object

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr: Exactly, so if `ObjectType` was, say, `NSString *`, then using `ObjectType *` would expand to `NSString **`, which isn't what's intended. `ObjectType` seems correct.

Comment: Looks like misunderstanding. Lets get to lower level of abstraction.
Let us say, we have `@interface Some`. Then, in `Stack` we should have

    `@interface Stack<__covariant Some*>
     - (Some*)popObject;
     @property NSArray<Some*> *allObjects;
     @end`